# c# WPF how to produce a flashy warning

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm learning WPF, so bear with me.

I would like to have my WPF application flash in the user's face if a certain event is fired.

What is the best way to "notify" the user? I really want the user to react!

Cheers, Patrick

Environment: Windows7/64bit/.Net4

Comment: Do you want them to annoy them like that so that your application is promptly uninstalled and thrown away? Flash the icon in the taskbar or show a notification near the system tray.

Comment: s/system tray/notification area/

Comment: Matthew, thanks for your comment. Normally I'm with you: Who needs all those "Are you sure?" questions. But I was asking because my simple app (which only I use) should remind me to do things at a certain time. Can you point me to a keyword for flashing an icon in the notification area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the user to react you can force them to by simply opening a modal dialogue. The most lightweight of which being the [MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messagebox.show.aspx). You can also create normal modal windows using their [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) method, you can make those windows as "fancy" as you want by getting rid of their normal appearance. This is achieved by setting the [`WindowStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstyle.aspx) to `None` and [`AllowsTransparency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.allowstransparency.aspx) to `true`, this will remove all the frame elements, so the window is now pure content.

[`Popups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) are handy for non-modal notifications and they already are content-only, but setting their `AllowsTransparency` to true may also be desired if you want rounded corners for example.

Comment: Glad to hear that, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you want to. (If an answer solved your problem that even is what you should do as per the system)

Answer (score 0):

Best is entirely subjective and depends on many context variables but here is how I do it MVVM style.

In your main view model, define a property

```
pubic ObservableCollection<AlertViewModel"> Alerts { get; private set; }
```

in my case the AlertViewModel has only a "Message" property and a "Dismiss" RelayCommand.

In the XAML of your main view add

```
<Grid>
    <all of my other other view controls>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="AlertsControl" Opacity="50" ItemsSource="{Binding Alerts}"/>
</Grid>
```

Make sure it is the last item in the main container of your main view.  This ensures it has the highest z order and will appear on top of all other controls.

Here is the data template for this view model

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AlertViewModel}">
   <Border CornerRadius="10" Margin="3" Background="Red">
     <Grid>
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
         <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <Button Margin="10" Grid.Column="0" 
               Command="{Binding ElementName=theWindow, Path=DataContext.DismissAlarmCommand}" 
               CommandParameter="{Binding}">Dismiss</Button>
       <TextBlock  Foreground="White" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Grid.Column="1" 
               Text="{Binding Message}"  FontSize="20" 
               VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
     </Grid>
   </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now,

```
Alerts.Add( new AlertViewModel() { Message = "Danger Will Robinson! Danger!" } );
```

Will pop a Bright red alert box onto the top of your main form.  It does not go away until the user presses "Dismiss"

If you want it to flash or fade in and out or bounce up and down you can add animation in the data template.

You can use a Converter or data to Enable/Disable the rest of the controls in the app byt binding to AlertsControl.HasItems

Good luck.

Comment: thrag, thank you for your answer! Although I prefer MVP over MVVM, I think I can still use your approach (thanks for the code snippet!) in combination with H.B.'s approach.